# Create column that shows distinct count of another column for its own group in DAX or Python

Tags: sql, pandas, join, powerbi, dax

I have a table where I want to filter down to only those rows where the group that row belongs to is found to have only a single unique value.
For example, if I am grouping the following data by the `index` column, I want to count the unique values of `foo` in each group and then drop any rows where there is more than just one value of `foo`

Example Input:

```
   index  foo
0      A   10
1      A   20
2      A   30
3      B   10
4      B   20
5      B   30
6      C   10
7      C   20
8      C   30
9      D   10
10     D   10
11     D   10
12     E   10
13     E   20
14     E   30
15     F   10
16     F   10
17     F   10
```

Expected Output:

```
  index  foo
0     D   10
1     D   10
2     D   10
3     F   10
4     F   10
5     F   10
```

I am able to do this in Python but am having trouble implementing the same solution in DAX (Power BI).

This is my Python approach:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'index': {0: "A", 1: "A", 2: "A", 3: "B", 4: "B", 5: "B", 6: "C",
                               7: "C", 8: "C", 9: "D", 10: "D", 11: "D", 12: "E",
                               13: "E", 14: "E", 15: "F", 16: "F", 17: "F"},
                     'foo': {0: 10, 1: 20, 2: 30, 3: 10, 4: 20, 5: 30, 6: 10,
                             7: 20, 8: 30, 9: 10, 10: 10, 11: 10, 12: 10,
                             13: 20, 14: 30, 15: 10, 16: 10, 17: 10}})


# count distinct values of "foo"
foo_distinct = data.groupby('index').agg(lambda x: len(set(x)))

# add the distinct value counts of foo to main table
joined_data = data.set_index('index').join(foo_distinct, rsuffix='_distinctgroupcount')
        
# filter out any values where there is more than a single distinct value
filtered_data = joined_data.loc[lambda df: df['foo_distinctgroupcount'] == 1])
```

And my attempt in DAX. The calculation of `foo_distinct` works as expected but I am having trouble getting the distinct group counts merged into the original data set (the attempt to get `joined_data` does not work).

```
foo_distinct = SUMMARIZE(data, data[index], "foo_distinctgroupcount", DISTINCTCOUNT(data[foo]))
            
joined_data = CALCULATETABLE(NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN(data, foo_distinct), USERELATIONSHIP(data[index], foo_distinct[index]))
```

My questions:

- Is this problem best solved by groupby, distinctcount, and joining those values back in to the original data or is there a more efficient/elegant approach?
- I believe I see that `NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN` can't be done since `data` and `foo_distinct` do not share a relationship (but they should since they are derived from the same source; however this function does not accept a `USERELATIONSHIP` call as far as I can tell. Is there a function that is more flexible for handling this? For example SQL would have the `ON` keyword available.

Comment: The key here is `groupby` + `transform`. Transform broadcasts the aggregated result back to every row that group belonged to in the original DataFrame, making it an easy and efficient way to filter entire groups from your DataFrame based on an aggregated result.

Answer (score 3):

you can try groupby with transform (*consider a distinct count over a window partition by index*) and nunique , then filter in values where the distinct count is 1:

```
df[df.groupby("index")['foo'].transform('nunique')==1]
```

---

```
   index  foo
9      D   10
10     D   10
11     D   10
15     F   10
16     F   10
17     F   10
```

With DAX you can try `DISTINCTCOUNT` with `EARLIER` over `index` and then use a `FILTER` maybe to filter `DISTINCTCOUNT('index')=1` (*have not tried but you can try something like this*)

Comment: Thanks for the help; that's a great method to know about. As far as DAX goes, I will try to employ what you mentioned here. If using earlier, wouldn't that require sorting the data first? It feels like there should be something more like transform in DAX, or at least it would be nice.

Comment: @teepee I was guessing, RADO has an answer for you in dax :) my guess was creating a calculated column with distinct counts and then use it as a reference to to create another table

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to create a new table using DAX:

```
Desired Output = 
VAR foo_distinct =
    FILTER (
        SUMMARIZE ( Data, Data[index], "Foo Count", DISTINCTCOUNT ( Data[foo] ) ),
        [Foo Count] = 1
    )
RETURN CALCULATETABLE ( Data, foo_distinct )
```

Result is a new table in the data model:

[image]

The way it works:

- First, filter the summary table to keep only indexes where distinct foo count = 1. This step creates a list of unique indexes.
- Then, filter the original data by the list of unique indexes.

I have to say that your second measure is very confusing - it involves other tables and relations that are not described in your input and desired output. If your goal is different, please elaborate.